# java zkoss EventListener how to get variables of event

Tags: java, zk

I debug from EventListener in InteliJ IDEA and get some variables like _val, _oldVal, _selbk, _start, _name ... But I don't know how to get those variables.
Here is my code:

```
myDoublebox.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGE, new org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
        //just for debug
        System.out.println(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data of the object Event using the getter methods.
Like:

- `event.getData()` returns the value of the event (the object set as the value of the event)
- `event.getName()` returns what kind of event it is

You can get all the informations here:
: https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/event/Event.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this

```
    yDoublebox.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGE, new org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)event.getData();
            String _val = (String) data.get("_val");
            Double _oldVal = (Double) data.get("_oldVal");
            Double _selbk = (Double) data.get("_selbk");
    }
});
```